# Add event listener to items inside flex container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, flexbox

I have a flex container that contains several items that have the `flex-grow` property set to 1 and a certain `max-width`.

[image]

I want to add an event listener to the group of items, but I do not want the event to fire if the event location is in the empty space of the flex container. For example, for a `click` event, I want the event to fire only if the blue space of the image below is clicked.

[image]

If I add the event listener to the parent container, the event fires even if I click the purple. If I add the event listener to the child items, the event does not fire when if I click on the margins of the items. In addition, for events like `onmouseenter` or `onmouseleave`, the event fires 3 times if I move my mouse over all the items, whereas my desire is for it to only fire once.

Here is a snippet of the current scenario:

```js
$(".flex-container").on("mouseenter", () => {
    $("#hidden").show();
})

$(".flex-container").on("mouseleave", () => {
    $("#hidden").hide();
})

$(".flex-item").on("mouseenter", () => {
    $("#hidden2").show();
})

$(".flex-item").on("mouseleave", () => {
    $("#hidden2").hide();
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 24px;
    max-width: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#hidden, #hidden2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    3
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">
  Flex Container Hovered
</div>

<div id="hidden2">
  Flex Item Hovered
</div>
```

Adding an extra flex container as a wrapper achieves close to the intended effect, but the intention of the `flex-grow` property of the items is not preserved, as seen below.

[image]

The items do not grow to the `max-width` of the items to fill up the outer box. Here is a snippet of the above scenario:

```js
$(".flex-container").on("mouseenter", () => {
    $("#hidden").show();
})

$(".flex-container").on("mouseleave", () => {
    $("#hidden").hide();
})

$(".flex-item").on("mouseenter", () => {
    $("#hidden2").show();
})

$(".flex-item").on("mouseleave", () => {
    $("#hidden2").hide();
})

$(".extra-wrapper").on("mouseenter", () => {
    $("#hidden3").show();
})

$(".extra-wrapper").on("mouseleave", () => {
    $("#hidden3").hide();
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.extra-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 24px;
    max-width: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#hidden, #hidden2, #hidden3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="extra-wrapper">
    <div class="flex-item">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">
  Flex Container Hovered
</div>

<div id="hidden2">
  Flex Item Hovered
</div>

<div id="hidden3">
  Extra Wrapper Hovered
</div>
```

How do I add an event listener to the items in a flex container when the items have a `flex-grow` and a `max-width` property?

Comment: Please post code as a [mcve].

Comment: [How do I include an element's margin in the hot-spot for jQuery's hover() event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298558/how-do-i-include-an-elements-margin-in-the-hot-spot-for-jquerys-hover-event/11298589)

Comment: @zer00ne Do the JSfiddles not count as the reproducible examples?

Comment: @ourmandave If the flex items' margins were included the hot-spot, if I mouse over the flex items in a line, the event would still fire 3 times, once per item in the box. I want the event to only fire once. I guess an option could be looking at the `e.toElement` to see where the mouse is entering to prevent a re-fire, but it seems more complicated than somehow wrapping all 3 items in a single parent element.

Comment: @wahoowa the reason why SO requires a [mcve] is because future readers will always have the code here on this site where as a link elsewhere is not gautunteed to always be there.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/sean7777/zngdr51k/11/

#### How 2 make it work

It works because since margin does not count in `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` events, we use a wrapper element around the `flex-item`, `wrap`. The wrapper then gets assigned padding, and you attach the event listener to the wrapper.

This way you can simulate `margin` as padding and make it work with the event listner.

###### Note that you will have to assign width and height to the box. In the example, if you remove the width/height, it won't look right.

Comment: Thanks, but there are still a few things missing for my specific use case. First, if you hover over all 3 boxes, the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events fire every time, as seen when doing `console.log` in the event handler: https://jsfiddle.net/Lw7sjteh/ . Second, the `height` property cannot be set, because then the `flex-grow` property does not work when sizing down the screen. I want the boxes to become smaller when the screen size is smaller, and expand up to `max-width` when the screen size is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324811/4157513) from @ourmandave, I came up with the following solution.

In this solution, I added a pseudo element to each `flex-item` so that I could include the elements' margins in the events' "hot spots" as they were called. I then used additional logic to prevent the event handlers from repeated triggers by using the event's [related target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7761228/4157513). By checking where the cursor *used* to be upon `mouseleave` or `mouseenter` events, one can prevent the event handlers from being fired again when the mouse moves from one flex item to another flex item. This solution still preserves the desired effects of `flex-grow` and `max-width`.

```js
$(".flex-container").on("mouseenter", () => {
    $("#hidden").show();
})

$(".flex-container").on("mouseleave", () => {
    $("#hidden").hide();
})

$(".flex-item").on("mouseenter", (e) => {
    if (e.relatedTarget.className === "flex-item") return;
    console.log('mouseenter fired');
    $("#hidden2").show();
})

$(".flex-item").on("mouseleave", (e) => {
    if (e.relatedTarget.className === "flex-item") return;
    console.log('mouseleave fired');
    $("#hidden2").hide();
})
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.item-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 24px;
    max-width: 24px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

.flex-item::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    inset: -10px -10px -10px -10px;
}

#hidden, #hidden2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    3
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">
  Flex Container Hovered
</div>

<div id="hidden2">
  Flex Item Hovered
</div>
```